# MYSQL INNER JOIN where attribute does not exist for one row

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, right-join

I have one Mysql table (CONFIGS) that looks like this:

```
+---------+
| config  |
+---------+
| ie8     |
| Firefox |
| Chrome  |
+---------+
```

I have another table (PROJECTS) that looks like:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------+
| config  | name           | passed_count |
+---------+----------------+--------------+
| Firefox | Project 1      |            0 |
| Chrome  | Project 1      |            3 |
| Chrome  | Project 2      |            1 |
| Firefox | Project 2      |            0 |
| ie8     | Project 2      |            0 |
+---------+----------------+--------------+
```

I want the final result to look like:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------+
| config  | name           | passed_count |
+---------+----------------+--------------+
| Firefox | Project 1      |            0 |
| Chrome  | Project 1      |            3 |
| ie8     | Project 1      |            0 |
| Chrome  | Project 2      |            1 |
| Firefox | Project 2      |            0 |
| ie8     | Project 2      |            0 |
+---------+----------------+--------------+
```

Basically I want all PROJECTS to be associated with all CONFIGS

```
| ie8     | Project 1      |            0 |
```

This is the other field that I want to be added

I tried various LEFT JOINS, RIGHT JOINS but could not get this to work. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: where did this record come from?
**| ie8     | Project 1      |            0 |**

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Please show those attempts you've made. Maybe it's just an easy thing to fix.

Comment: Don't you have a table with projects as well? The current table you have, actually seems to be the joined table (project/browser associations)

Comment: | ie8     | Project 1      |            0 |

came since there is no IE8 for Project 1 in PROJECTS table. This is what I want to add to final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate all the possible combinations and then use a `left join`.  Here is an example:

```
select c.config, n.name, coalesce(p.passed_count, 0) as passed_count
from config c cross join
     (select distinct name from projects p) n left join
     projects p
     on p.name = n.name and p.config = c.config;
```

Comment: Was it not possible to use a cross join and then group by name and config? Cross join should already generate all combinations of the two tables or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. Let me test that if this will work.

Comment: Thanks @Gorgon. I was forgetting to do a CROSS JOIN that was causing the issue.